# JSP tag files: Exception inside of <c:set> results with a blank screen if it is executed inside of a tag file's body stored in a variable

Tags: jsp, error-handling, exception, jstl, jsp-tags

Let's say I have this very simple JSP tag file called `show-body.tag`:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<jsp:doBody var="body"/>
${body}
```

All it does is it outputs the body of the tag (my tag is more complicated but this is for simplicity sake). Then, from a JSP page I will use this tag like this to get an error (`wrong.key` does not exist):

```
<myTag:show-body>
  <c:set var="x">
    <bean:message key="wrong.key"/>
  </c:set>
  ${x}
</myTag:show-body>
```

This will end up with a blank screen and 200 request status code instead of forwarding me to my error page.

If I take the code out of `<c:set>`, everything works fine, meaning I am properly forwarded to my error page with 500 status code:

```
<myTag:show-body>
  <bean:message key="wrong.key"/>
</myTag:show-body>
```

Also, having an exception thrown in `<c:set>` but outside of custom tag's body works fine:

```
<c:set var="x">
  <bean:message key="wrong.key"/>
</c:set>
${x}
```

Also, not storing the tag body in a variable inside of the custom tag file results with the error page properly showing:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" description="Outputs tabs" %>
<jsp:doBody />
```

However, it's the combination of these three that causes the blank screen issue. Why is this happening? Is this a bug inside of JSP or should I be using some special way to set attributes inside of a body of a tag file?

Our current workaround is to replace:

```
<jsp:doBody var="body"/>
${body}
```

with:

```
<c:set var="body">
  <jsp:doBody/>
</c:set>
${body}
```

We are using Tomcat 8 Servlet 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a custom tag you should use the `<jsp:attribute>` tag, take a look at this [docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnalj/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. Using `<jsp:attribute>` as a body works well when exception occurs. However, this changes the syntax in the JSP page and I would like to be able to use actual body of the tag.

Comment: For clarification, the example sets `x` variable inside of a JSP page. That variable is not supposed to be passed as an attribute to the custom tag. It should simply be outputted in the tag's body.